# Javascript How to Use image alt tag as alt within Glightbox?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently using Glightbox and when I click on the lightbox this image carousel appears, but the image alt tag has no content.
I have checked a lot of documents and information but still can't solve it. Please help me solve it. Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
       <head>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/glightbox/3.2.0/css/glightbox.min.css" />
        </head>
<body>
<div id="glightbox-demo">
    
<h2>Single Images</h2>
  <a href="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3712/9032543579_1217e6566b_b.jpg" class="glightbox">
    <img alt="demo alt1!" src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3712/9032543579_1217e6566b_s.jpg" />
  </a> 
  <a href="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3818/9036037912_83576fe5ab_b.jpg" class="glightbox">
   <img alt="demo alt2!" src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3818/9036037912_83576fe5ab_s.jpg" />
  </a>  
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/glightbox/3.2.0/js/glightbox.min.js"></script>
<script>
const lightbox = GLightbox({

});
 </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```